# How to create a map showing NDVI result in erdas?

Tags: cartography, erdas-imagine, ndvi

I'm using Spot 5 image to run an NDVI analysis. The band that I used in processing is 4,3,2. The area was 80% covered by mangrove.
My problem here how can I create a map to show or present the result?
Basically I run the NDVI using the function automatically under unsupervised > ndvi in erdas.